# Rails 4: How to "Duplicate" or Change State of Records from model 'A' to model 'B'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, invoices

I have model Quote and model Invoice.
The database for each of these models have the columns: date, company, product and price.
When a customer approves a quote I would like to turn that quote into a invoice with the same values but with the current date and its own invoice_id.

What code should I include in my Invoice model so that the record "duplicates" or "changes" state?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quote you can use the following code

```
after_save :generate_invoice, :if => :approved?

def approved?
 # your code to return true or false, this method should return true only one time, handle it carefully.
end

def generate_invoice
    Invoice.create!(date: Time.now, company: self.company, product: self.product, price: self.price)
end
```

Comment: yes, but you need to determine or track that quote has been approved.

Comment: So I am thinking of adding an approved checkbox in the form. Thus, it would be  `def approved?
 approved = true
end`    ?

Comment: yes you can try this, and read the comment's in approved? method.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying, But it seems every Quote should have one invoice, you can add an attribute 'approved' on form  then def approved?  approved  end this will return true/false.